# Using pdb with supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn, supervisord

I am running my django app using `docker compose`. `Ngninx` and `gunicorn` are run via `supervisor`.

However I can't seem to figure out how to debug using `pdb`. When I use:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

After running the command `docker-compose up`, my app and database begin to run and the terminal screen remains active waiting for further output to display.

When my code reaches `pdb.set_trace()`, the aforementioned terminal remains as is but the `(pdb)` interface does not appear.

Would anyone know how I might be able to debug my application using `pdb`? Is there something else that I need to use?

Thank you.

**Update**

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    container_name: my_container_name
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
      MYSQL_USER: "myusername"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "mypass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mypass"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    command: mysqld

  web:
    build: .
    container_name: my_container_name
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`supervisord.conf`

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx

[program:djangoserver]
command=python /myapp/djangorest/manage.py runserver localhost:8000
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Comment: You are running supervisor as PID 1, this approach won't work. You need to use separate containers for nginx and djnagoserver

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you for this. Finally got it working after separating the containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to debug then you will have to take gunicorn out of picture and directly launch django using `django manage.py runserver`.

Gunicorn will launch threads or processes in background and it is difficult to attach to their stdin. So you want the main PID 1 to have the stdin and attach to same. You will need to make changed to your `docker-compose.yml` and add below parameters to your django service

```
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Then `docker-compose` doesn't allow to connect to stdin, so you need to launch the same in detached mode

```
docker-compose up -d
```

After that you want to connect to the django container using `docker` directly

```
docker attach <project>_<djangocontainername>_1
```

Then when you debug the `(pdb)` terminal will show

Comment: Thanks Tarun. When I do it this way, the output states that the djangoserver is running however in reality it doesn't appear to be (when I run my app, it doesn't work - I have to manually run the `runserver` command within the container). Would you know why this might be?

Comment: Update the final docker-compose you used in the question

Comment: I have updated my answer with my latest files. Please note: If I move the `command`, `stdin` and `tty` to `docker-compose.yml`, then I receive an error stating `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '172.18.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")`. PS: I accidentally edited your answer - hopefully you or someone else can reject the edit.